# Graphics object making blank images

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, image-processing, gdi+

I'm trying to draw images to return as base 64 strings over a web service in .net 4.5. I can get as far as loading a custom background, but then I need to draw text onto that background. The problem is, once I go from Image->Graphics object->Image, I end up with a blank png. If I return the original srcImage (the blank template) over the service, everything works, but my label is blank so I know it must be a problem with my graphics object somewhere.

My code is:

```
    var labelSize = new Size(400, 459);
    using (var srcImage = Image.FromFile(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/images/labels/" + labelImageFilename))) {
        PixelFormat format = srcImage.PixelFormat;
        using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(labelSize.Width, labelSize.Height, format))
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)) {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height);
            Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0,0, labelSize.Width, labelSize.Height);
            g.DrawImage(srcImage, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            // draw other shapes etc

            g.FillRegion(Brushes.Blue,new Region(new Rectangle(0,0,200,200)));
            g.Clear(Color.Red);
            g.Flush();
            return new Bitmap(srcImage, labelSize.Width, labelSize.Height); // this works fine, but my image is just the standard background I'm using
            return new Bitmap(labelSize.Width, labelSize.Height, g); //  returns a blank image
        }
    }
```

Nothing is drawn, neither the template background (srcImage), not the red or blue rectangles.

Comment: I think it looks like your graphics object is drawing on newImage, but you are returning srcImage. If you want to return the result of your drawing, I think you need to return newImage ? I'm not 100% sure, so hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: In left the top line in to show that the calls to the web service are working, it's the second, final line which is actually returned.

Comment: Try something like: return new Bitmap(newImage, labelSize.Width, labelSize.Height);

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a gent. If you post that as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: return new Bitmap(labelSize.Width, labelSize.Height, g) won't work. As per MSDN this constructor will only initialize Bitmap with the graphics resolution but it won't save its content to bitmap. You should return newImage object as proposed by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it looks like your graphics object is drawing on newImage, but you are returning srcImage. If you want to return the result of your drawing, I think you need to return newImage.

Try something like:

```
return new Bitmap(newImage, labelSize.Width, labelSize.Height);
```